QTest Unit Test: Undefined symbol
I am trying to write unit tests for my application. On my first attempt, the build of my unit test fails to link due to an undefined symbol.
ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: AnalysisEngine::diagnosisDetected(Diagnosis)
>>> referenced by ../code/core/src/analysisengine.cpp:18
>>>               ../code/core/src/analysisengine.cpp.obj:(AnalysisEngine::parseBuffer())
>>> referenced by ../code/core/src/analysisengine.cpp:22
>>>               ../code/core/src/analysisengine.cpp.obj:(AnalysisEngine::parseBuffer())
>>> referenced by ../code/core/src/analysisengine.cpp:26
>>>               ../code/core/src/analysisengine.cpp.obj:(AnalysisEngine::parseBuffer())

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: AnalysisEngine::staticMetaObject
>>> referenced by ../code/core/src/analysisengine.cpp.obj:(.refptr._ZN14AnalysisEngine16staticMetaObjectE)

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: vtable for AnalysisEngine
>>> referenced by ../code/core/src/analysisengine.cpp.obj:(.refptr._ZTV14AnalysisEngine)

My unit test depends on and instantiates an AnalysisEngine() class. This links and builds just fine in my normal application, but for some reason has issues with this the diagnosisDetected signal. How is it that the linker can't find this? (all relevant code below)
.h
#ifndef ANALYSISENGINE_H
#define ANALYSISENGINE_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QTimer>
#include "framebuffer.h"
#include "diagnosis.h"

class AnalysisEngine : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit AnalysisEngine(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    bool flatliningCheck();
    bool tachycardiaCheck();
    bool arrhythmiaCheck();

signals:
    void diagnosisDetected(Diagnosis diagnosis);

private:
    QTimer analysisTimer;
    FrameBuffer* buffer;
    void parseBuffer();
};

#endif // ANALYSISENGINE_H

Relevant part of .cpp

#include "analysisengine.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <cmath>

AnalysisEngine::AnalysisEngine(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{
    connect(&analysisTimer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &AnalysisEngine::parseBuffer);
    analysisTimer.start(3000);  // Run analysis every two seconds
}

void AnalysisEngine::parseBuffer() {
    QMutexLocker locker(buffer->lock());

    if (flatliningCheck()) {
        qDebug() << "Diagnosis Detected: FLATLINE";
        emit diagnosisDetected(Diagnosis::FLATLINING);
    }
    if (tachycardiaCheck()) {
        qDebug() << "Diagnosis Detected: TACHYCARDIA";
        emit diagnosisDetected(Diagnosis::TACHYCARDIA);
    }
    if (arrhythmiaCheck()) {
        qDebug() << "Diagnosis Detected: ARRHYTHMIA";
        emit diagnosisDetected(Diagnosis::ARRHYTHMIA);
    }
}

diagnosis.h contains the enum used int he signal and is included in analysisengine.h
#ifndef DIAGNOSIS_H
#define DIAGNOSIS_H

enum class Diagnosis {
    FLATLINING,
    TACHYCARDIA,
    ARRHYTHMIA
};

#endif // DIAGNOSIS_H

My unit test (Qtest) cmakelists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(CoreUnitTests LANGUAGES CXX)

enable_testing()

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Gui Test)
find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Gui Test)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_executable(CoreUnitTests tst_TestAnalysisEngine.cpp
                             test_analysisengine.h
                             ../../code/core/src/analysisengine.cpp
                             ../../code/core/src/framebuffer.cpp
                             ../../code/core/inc/diagnosis.h)

add_test(NAME TestAnalysisEngine COMMAND TestAnalysisEngine)

target_include_directories(CoreUnitTests PRIVATE
    ../../code/core/inc  # Add the core headers to the include path
    ./
)

target_link_libraries(CoreUnitTests PRIVATE Qt6::Gui Qt6::Test)


I am assuming that the QTest CMakeLists.txt is in some kind of sub-directory of you main CMakeLists.txt? If so, the scope to your main program is actually available to you inside the tests directory. Use that instead of ../... I.e ${MAIN_PROJECT_NAME}/code/core....

The code that is reference in your error message is not shown in your example.

CMakeList.txt is so broken. 1. You should have a library for production code AnalysisEngine. 2. Test should be separate target which is linked to production code library. 3. You should make sure that mock is generated for a header file: analysisengine.h so signal code is generated.

Why do I need a library for production code? In (almost) all of the examples I've seen this is not a requirement (e.g. https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qttestlib-tutorial1-example.html). Are you saying for every individual class/element I want to unit test I will need to create separate libraries for and rebuild before every update to my unit tests?

Currently my CMakeLists.txt shown above lives inside the directory containing my main project CMakeLists.txt, but it is not identified as a sub-directory. It is it's own top-level file. Should that be different? Shouldn't it be able to work as a standalone as long as I have the proper includes?
